# Wrapped TextView in a layout with other views

Tags: android, android-layout

Let's look at the following layout:

[image: example]

Now let's make some constraints:

- TextView must be aligned to the left
- Image must be aligned to textView's text from the left
- CheckBox must be aligned to the right
- TextView might be 2 lines or more (might be a very long text or a short one)

So the way I want it to behave is that as long as the text is short enough the remaining space will be between image and checkBox.

However if the text is long enough I just need the textView to split in to 2 lines,
because it is long enough the image will get pushed until it is aligned to the check box as well. (but it is still aligned to the textView...)

If I use a LinearLayout I have to make the textView with width 0 and weight 1 in order it to split when there is no more room, however in that case image will not be aligned to textView's text....

So I need to put some sort of spacer between image and checkBox with weight as well but then it will break the textView's weight.

A relative layout will not let the textView know when it is time to split....

A hardcoded width for the textView will not play nice as well, because image will not be aligned to the text, and different devices has different widths.

A textView with drawableRight doesn't work as well.

Any idea how can I achieve this behavior?

Comment: you have to use weight and linear layout in order to achieve it and set the width and weight according to your need also align the elements. it will work fine..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

Set you image to right-drawable of TextView

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/checkbox"
        android:gravity="left">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_launcher" // here set you image
            android:text="android demo text"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: nice! , you can change the linearLayout to be frameLayout.
Tnx!

Answer (score 0):

try like this may help you,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="85"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

              <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:text="android demo text"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="15"
            android:gravity="center|right"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: in this solution the sizes are not dynamic because the check box will always take certain space (because of the 15 weight) so the wrapped text can only grow until 85 weight, and there might be big space left..
thinks of a big tablet, and a lot of text, the line will break and there will still be a lot of space left it the line.
on the other hand, if checkBox is big enough on a small device it might be bigger the 15 weight of the line, so it will not be shown correctly